# Is it common to work concurrently on projects with PIs other than your advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, collaboration

Is this a common occurrence? Or is there some expectation to remain loyal to one's advisor and only do projects related to his/her vision. Field is computer science.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It very much depends on your relationship with your PI, funding sources, etc. For example, a PI might discourage this kind of work if you are solely funded by one of their grants, wherein they need most/all of your research output heading toward a specific objective. On the other hand, it might be *necessary* to work on other projects if you have a gap in funding and need to take a research assistantship elsewhere for a semester or two.

In my own experience, even within a given department (or even a given *PI*), there's also a component of how interested a given student is in pursuing other projects, and how well they balance their time.

Comment: I completely concur.  My advisor encouraged me to work with other PIs as well.  Some of my friends in grad school would have been strongly rebuked for doing the same.